# How to prevent apps from showing previews on lock screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications, privacy

When I receive a message I don't want the sender or a preview of the content be shown on my lock screen. Some apps (like iMessage and Mail) allow you to set this in iOS' Settings -> Notifications. Other apps (like Viber) allow you to set this internally from their settings. But there are apps (like Skype), for which I don't see a way to set this. Is it possible to set this globally for all apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like every app determines what to show on its notifications; I don't see a global switch.

You can, however, turn the lock screen notification off.

Find it on Settings > Notifications > [App], look for "Show on lock screen" and turn it off to disallow the app to show its notifications when the phone is locked.

[image: skype notifications]

Skype does not have the "Show Previews" switch available at the Notifications settings for Messages –and I can't find anything about that subject on the [support site](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12404/how-do-i-manage-skype-notifications-on-ios), but [plenty](http://community.skype.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-and-iPad/Turn-off-message-preview-on-lock-screen/td-p/3943706) of [people](http://community.skype.com/t5/iOS-archive/iphone-app-Notifications/td-p/1338509) [asking](http://community.skype.com/t5/iOS-archive/How-to-disable-message-preview-on-iOS-7-1/td-p/2987912) the [same](http://community.skype.com/t5/iOS-archive/Turn-off-message-preview-on-lock-screen/td-p/1644078) with no response– so it appears that each app controls what it's shown on the notification.

[image: messages app ios notification settings: show preview]

Comment: I don't want to turn off the notification all together, I just want it not to show a preview of the contents of the message, as well as the sender.

Comment: Oh, ok. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I added more info, but no luck on controlling what is shown if the app itself does not have some sort of setting for that.